# Populating a template with data from csv with spaces in bash

Tags: bash, csv, templates, scripting, sh

I am working on a script to read data from csv and populate a template. This 'populated template' is then saved in a different file.

Here is exactly what my script generates right now.

It takes this template (example)

```
Data:
Column 1: VAR_COL1
Column 2: VAR_COL2
Column 3: VAR_COL3
```

and populates it with data from this csv

```
817273284,ABC1,data1
2394294234,ABC2,data2
```

The output is this and it should be like this.

```
Data:
Column 1: 817273284
Column 2: ABC1
Column 3: data1

Data:
Column 1: 2394294234
Column 2: ABC2
Column 3: data2
```

The problem I am facing is that the script breaks when there is a space in one of the 'cells' in the csv file. I would like it to work with spaces. I am new to bash so quite clueless.

I would appreciate any guidance; here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
IMPORT="./data/file.csv"
TEMPLATE="./data/temp.txt"

for i in `cat ${IMPORT}`
do 
  VAR_COL1=`echo $i | awk -F, '{print $1}'`
  VAR_COL2=`echo $i | awk -F, '{print $2}'`
  VAR_COL3=`echo $i | awk -F, '{print $3}'`
  cat $TEMPLATE | sed -e s/VAR_COL1/$VAR_COL1/g \
                  -e s/VAR_COL2/$VAR_COL2/g \
                  -e s/VAR_COL3/$VAR_COL3/g \
            >> ./output/output-temp.txt
 done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in `for in $(cat ...)` part. Space in a line makes two different iterations of `for` cycle.

Example:

For `testfile.txt` with this content:

```
11 22
33
```

Executing following script

```
for i in $(cat !$)
do
    echo $i
done
```

Gives output:

```
11
22
33
```

Instead of desired:

```
11 22
33
```

To properly iterate over lines in a file, see answers to https://superuser.com/questions/284187/bash-iterating-over-lines-in-a-variable

P.S. use

```
$(command)
```

over

```
`command`
```

because `$()` can be nested and it is more readable.

Comment: So I removed the for loop and changed it to cat `$IMPORT | while read -r i;` but now I am getting a `unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`. 
Any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Do you really need `-r` flag in `read` call? Also, put sed expressions into double quotes. Unless there is a special case, all bash variables (`$VAR_COL1`) [should be quoted](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html).

Comment: Great it worked! Appreciate the help and thank you so much. I am facing a really minor issue where the script does not process the last line but processes everything else. I think it needs a newline char at the end. I suppose I can get around it by just putting having an extra blank line at the end of my data.csv

Comment: Wouldn't it be more logical to put extra line in the template? Also, what will happen if csv data will contain a substring "VAR_COL1"?

Comment: I meant to say that the script doesn't process the last line of the csv. Meaning it doesnt create a 'populated template' for the last row of data.csv. But it does when there is a blank line at the end of the data.csv.
If csv data contains a VAR_COL1 the script seems to work fine.

Comment: My mistake, sed only changes text from template, and doesn't affect text from csv (which is processed with awk).